# Submitted transaction not propagated to all nodes

Tags: transactions, mining, nethereum

I have a private ethereum blockchain network running set up in 3 nodes using geth.
If i submit a transaction(smart contract function call) to one node and go to another node and type in eth.pendingTransactions it is returning empty.

I want to be able to submit a transaction to one node and mine it using any node in the network. But currently I am able to mine from the same network only. Why is that ?

P.s. I am using Nethereum to interface with the geth node and make function calls.

Comment: Bump. anyone ??

Comment: Are the nodes connected? ie admin.addPeer

Comment: Yes they are. I can see them through admin.peers and also the blocks are getting synced.

Comment: same thing happens to me. I have submitted a EIP155 transaction to one node which is mining, but has no mining power, but the transaction is not propagated to other nodes which have mining power.

Comment: Maybe this has to do with the bug in geth 1.4.6.  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3694  .I am going to update my geth and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to a recent version will fix it. This issue was fixed in 1.6.0 probably with [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/13882) PR . You can choose your release version from here : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases